# How to insert tuples to a table (postgres) in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a list of tuples, where every tuple element belongs to a particular column, for example:

```
[("mike",19,"graduate"),("niko",22,"software engineer")....] 

model/table:
Name | Age | occupation
```

how do I insert every tuple into a table (I have the required model created already).  Just don't know how to insert into the database.

Please help and forgive me if I come off as an amateur. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list of objects, and then [**`.bulk_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) these:

```
data = [
    MyModel(name=name, age=age, occupation=occupation)
    for name, age, occupation in mylistoftuples
]

MyModel.objects.bulk_create(data)
```